# Delete directories only in Linux for directories > x days

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to write a script and delete the directories/files that > x days and ignore how old the files are inside the directories so only stay in that current level.

I have this:

```
find /home/terry -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +10 -exec ls -ltird {} \;
find /home/terry -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +10  -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

However, the first line does not return any directory and if I change -maxdepth to 2 it returned the files in second level. I would like to delete the directories in /home/terry that are over than 10 days old.

Comment: You have tagged this `kdb`  which is a database language. I suggest you edit to `bash` and/ or `shell` which makes more sense as this seems to be a generic Linux shell scripting question.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right in understanding what you said, you are looking to delete both files and directories that are over 10 days old from your personal home directory e.g. home/terry.

In doing this, a possible method is through adjusting your -type statement slightly so it allows for the selection of directories as well.

This can be done like the following below:

```
find /home/terry -maxdepth 1 -type f,d -mtime +10 -exec ls -ltird {} \;
find /home/terry -maxdepth 1 -type f,d -mtime +10  -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

where the change here is selecting both file and directories using multiple arguments e.g. f,d